# AspxGridView with a modal window,

Tags: modal-dialog, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have a AspxGridView and when i double click to a row, it shows a modal window. What i want to do is, send one columns' value to a AspxLabel which is at ModalWindow. But i couldn't manage to do it, in gridview i use ClientSideEvents RowDblClick to get row value. Here is the code:

GridView:

```
<dxwgv:ASPxGridView ID="gw_Parameters" runat="server" 

        CssFilePath="~/App_Themes/Aqua/{0}/styles.css" CssPostfix="Aqua" 

        AutoGenerateColumns="False" ClientInstanceName="grid" 

        OnCustomDataCallback="gw_Parameters_CustomDataCallback">

        <ClientSideEvents RowDblClick="function(s, e) {

    grid.GetValuesOnCustomCallback(e.visibleIndex, ShowModalWindow())

}" />
```

Script:

```
function ShowModalWindow(val)

    {

        pcc_Question.Show();

        lblCQuestionText.SetText(val);

    }
```

And c#:

```
protected void gw_Parameters_CustomDataCallback(object sender, ASPxGridViewCustomDataCallbackEventArgs e)

        {

            int visibleIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.Parameters);

            string fieldName = string.Empty;



            if (gw_Parameters.VisibleColumns[0] is GridViewCommandColumn)

                fieldName = ((GridViewDataColumn)gw_Parameters.VisibleColumns[3]).FieldName;

            else

                fieldName = ((GridViewDataColumn)gw_Parameters.VisibleColumns[2]).FieldName;



            e.Result = gw_Parameters.GetRowValues(visibleIndex, fieldName);



        }
```

Thanks for the help,

Mehmet Şerif Tozlu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks correct and should work.  I suggest that you set the breakpoint in the gw_Parameters_CustomDataCallback method and check the e.Result value.  Also, according to your code, the lblCQuestionText is the ClientInstanceName property of the label residing in the PopupControl.  Is it true?

Comment: <ClientSideEvents RowDblClick="function(s, e) {

    grid.GetValuesOnCustomCallback(e.visibleIndex, ShowModalWindow())

}" />

in here instead of "ShowModalWindow()", i should use "ShowModalWindow". So i fixed the problem, thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Mehmet,

Try [the results here](http://search.devexpress.com/?q=modal&p=T4|P5|57&d=447) which has several examples.